# New to Python using shutil cant find existing filepath

Tags: python, directory, shutil, file-copying

I'm new to python.  I'm trying to create a simple program that uses shutil to copy a folder within the C drive to another folder.  When copied I'd like to add the date/time to the end of the folder name in its new location.  This is used for file back up and cleanup.  Here is what I've got so far but it cant find the file path.  Eventually this has to save the copied files from a local PC to a network drive.

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

SOURCE = "C:/Program Files(x86) /FOLDER1/LOGS"
AppendDate=datetime.datetime.now()
BACKUP = "C:/Users/ME/Desktop/FOLDERNEW/LOGS %s" % AppendDate

shutil.copytree(SOURCE,BACKUP)
print os.listdir(BACKUP)
```

Comment: what does `print os.listdir(SOURCE)` print? (you have a space in front of ` /FOLDER1...`

Comment: `Program Files(x86) ` looks like a pretty obvious typo, given as it's `Program Files (x86)` out-of-the-box (space *before* the parenthesized piece, not after it).

Comment: It'd also be helpful to provide the exact error so we know *which* path isn't being found.

Comment: BTW, see [the PEP-8 Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) -- all-caps names are reserved for constants (and CamelCase is reserved for class names); names_with_underscores are the appropriate form for regular variables.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I had copied the file path in (I changed the names of the files/ instrument directories when I posted but didn't catch the caps when I did it.  Can't believe I missed the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the post because I can't 'comment' yet.

However, it looks like the error might be a single space omitted from your program file (x86) line.

```
SOURCE = "C:/Program Files (x86)/"
```

As for the Date, it will have to be appended in a format that windows except for naming folders.

[Best practices for file naming](https://library.stanford.edu/research/data-management-services/data-best-practices/best-practices-file-naming)

For this replace Appenddate characters using replace.

```
import re

cleandate = re.sub('[-!@#$:.]', '_', str(AppendDate))
```

This worked for me.

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os
import re



SOURCE = "C:/Program Files (x86)/HP"
AppendDate=datetime.datetime.now()
cleandate = re.sub('[-!@#$:.]', '_', str(AppendDate))
BACKUP = "C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/FOLDERNEW/LOGS %s" % cleandate

shutil.copytree(SOURCE,BACKUP)
print os.listdir(BACKUP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Python! Please try the following.

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os

SOURCE = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FOLDER1\\LOGS"
AppendDate=datetime.datetime.now()
BACKUP = "C:\\Users\ME\\Desktop\\FOLDERNEW\\LOGS %s" % AppendDate

shutil.copytree(SOURCE,BACKUP)
print os.listdir(BACKUP)
```

Windows uses a different directory separater than Unix, Linux and Mac. This character `\` also has another functionality as the prefix to escape sequences, so to generate a single `\` character in a Python string, you need to have two `\\` (i.e., it's the escape sequence for the `\` character itself) or use "raw" strings.

Also, as the other commentators pointed out, it looked like your path had a space in the wrong place.

Comment: The forward-slash separator *is* silently honored on Python for Windows. And if you're going to use the backslash, I'd suggest a raw string to have a bit more readability over doubling: `r'c:\Program Files (x86)\FOLDER1\LOGS'`